# Procedural vine, direction of leaves, problem with detached branches

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I create a procedural vine (or bean). But I have several problems with "leaves", "branches" and endpoints
[image]

1. Turn the leaves in the opposite direction from the branch (in the direction along the z-axis)
2. Is it possible to connect the branches to the stem or bring them closer?
   [image]

The third problem is not critical, but if you have a solution, I will be grateful. All "branches" are removed in order to highlight the main stem, because of this the very top part of the vine is also removed, is it possible to fix it?
[image]

*(Blender v 3.2.1)*
[image]

Comment: If you really want to use a mesh as a base here, then I would solve the leaves with vertex groups, because that's the only way you can reliably separate the leaves from the rest of the geometry. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: @quellenform Yes, I need a procedural liana, with leaves and how exactly it will be implemented is not very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question is actually three separate questions, here is the answer:

**Use vertex groups to mark the leaves.**

[image]
[image]

This way you can easily separate the geometry at the desired points and get your own curves for the stems.

1. This is practical because you can get a suitable rotation for the leaves directly from the curves with `Curve to Points`.
2. Also you can solve your second problem and get the next positions of the changed curve for your stems.
3. And the third problem is then self-explanatory, because you have clearly separated stem and stem from each other.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>